# How to split a Jenkinsfile into subfiles (“includes”)?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Our Jenkinsfile keeps growing and reached a point where it’s hard to keep track of everything. We would like to “split” some of the parts into their own subfiles (see “include for make” https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html for instance).

While looking for a solution, “shared libraries” https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ keep coming up. That’s basically what I want, but it seems to address a different problem (providing common/shared functionality across different Jenkinsfiles) and also adds a lot of complexity (additional git repository). We’re simply looking for a way to decrease the complexity of one big Jenkinsfile by splitting it into multiple smaller ones.

Did I oversee the solution in my research? Or is there currently no solution to manage tasks/stages/function from the Jenkinsfile into separate modules in the same repo?

Comment: Shared libraries do address your problem, but they also reduce complexity usually when utilizing multiple `Jenkinsfile`, and you do state you have only the one, so you are probably correct that it would not really reduce complexity for you.

Comment: Did you find a solution or workaround to your problem? I'm facing the same issue.